How to a flutter apps Bottom Navigation bar on top of all page
Actually Im making a Clone of Spotify using Flutter where I designed a Customized bottom navigation bar ..I want whichever Page I go , the bottom Navigation bar and music Player stack on top of the page ..heres my code of home screen where I made the bottom navigation bar and miniplayer
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _selectedIndex = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  DateTime? backButtonPressTime;

  void callback() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _selectedIndex.value = index;
    _pageController.jumpToPage(
      index,
    );
  }

  Future<bool> handleWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed =
        backButtonPressTime == null ||
            now.difference(backButtonPressTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 3);

    if (backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed) {
      backButtonPressTime = now;
      ShowSnackBar().showSnackBar(
        context,
        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.exitConfirm,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        noAction: true,
      );
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final bool rotated = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < screenWidth;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    if (rotated)
                      ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: _selectedIndex,
                        builder: (
                          BuildContext context,
                          int indexValue,
                          Widget? child,
                        ) {
                          return NavigationRail(
                            minWidth: 70.0,
                            groupAlignment: 0.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            selectedIndex: indexValue,
                            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                              _onItemTapped(index);
                            },
                            labelType: screenWidth > 1050
                                ? NavigationRailLabelType.selected
                                : NavigationRailLabelType.none,
                            selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                            unselectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                            ),
                            selectedIconTheme:
                                Theme.of(context).iconTheme.copyWith(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                            unselectedIconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
                            useIndicator: screenWidth < 1050,
                            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                            destinations: [
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                                  selectedIcon: 'assets/home_fill.svg',
                                  unselectedIcon: 'assets/home_outline.svg',
                                  indexChecker: indexValue == 0,
                                ),
                                label: const Text('Home'),
                              ),
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                                  selectedIcon: 'assets/search_fill.svg',
                                  unselectedIcon: 'assets/search_outline.svg',
                                  indexChecker: indexValue == 1,
                                ),
                                label: const Text('Search'),
                              ),
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                                  selectedIcon: 'assets/library_fill.svg',
                                  unselectedIcon: 'assets/library_outline.svg',
                                  indexChecker: indexValue == 2,
                                ),
                                label: const Text('Your Library'),
                              ),
                              NavigationRailDestination(
                                icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                                  selectedIcon: 'assets/yt_music_fill.svg',
                                  unselectedIcon: 'assets/yt_music_outline.svg',
                                  indexChecker: indexValue == 3,
                                ),
                                label: const Text('YT Music'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: PageView(
                              physics: const CustomPhysics(),
                              onPageChanged: (indx) {
                                _selectedIndex.value = indx;
                              },
                              controller: _pageController,
                              children: [
                                SaavnHomePage(),
                                const SearchPageScreen(),
                                const LibraryPage(),
                                const YouTube(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            //bottom Navigationbar
            if (!rotated)
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: _selectedIndex,
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, int indexValue, Widget? child) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 80 ,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                            Color.fromARGB(145, 0, 0, 0),
                            Color.fromARGB(90, 0, 0, 0),
                            Colors.transparent,
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          stops: [0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.75, 1.0],
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15 , top: 5,),
                      child: BottomNavigationBar(
                        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                              selectedIcon: 'assets/home_fill.svg',
                              unselectedIcon: 'assets/home_outline.svg',
                              indexChecker: indexValue == 0,
                            ),
                            label: 'Home',
                          ),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                              selectedIcon: 'assets/search_fill.svg',
                              unselectedIcon: 'assets/search_outline.svg',
                              indexChecker: indexValue == 1,
                            ),
                            label: 'Search',
                          ),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                              selectedIcon: 'assets/library_fill.svg',
                              unselectedIcon: 'assets/library_outline.svg',
                              indexChecker: indexValue == 2,
                            ),
                            label: 'Your Library',
                          ),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: BottomNavBarIcon(
                              selectedIcon: 'assets/yt_music_fill.svg',
                              unselectedIcon: 'assets/yt_music_outline.svg',
                              indexChecker: indexValue == 3,
                            ),
                            label: 'YT Music',
                          ),
                        ],
                        currentIndex: indexValue,
                        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                        unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                        selectedFontSize: 10,
                        unselectedFontSize: 10,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onTap: _onItemTapped,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: rotated ? 0.0 : 70.0,
              left: rotated ? screenWidth / 2 : 2.0,
              right: 2.0,
              child: MiniPlayer(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Heres The screenshot of the page :
Home Page:


So what's the problem you're facing right now with BottomNavigationBar in your code?

There are 2 solutions for your problem
1-> You can use a plugin that already has this kind of functionality implemented like this one (https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_navbar_player)
2-> You can implement your own logic and develop a custom solution. We can use material app's builder property (https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_navbar_player) to change or add anything to the whole app.

The Navigation bar not shown in other page rather than this 4 page
